# referencing Pandas dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to reference a pandas dataframe from another.

```
import pandas as pd

f1 = [['a',5,7],['b',7,9],['c',9,11],['d',11,13],['e',13,15],['f',15,17]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f1,columns=[1,2,3])
f2 = [['a','c','f'],['b','d',None]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=f2, columns=[1,2,3])
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

I want the output to be another dataframe that lists the values from df1 to df2.
The output should be

```
[
[[5,7],[9,11],[13,15]]
[[7,9],[11,13],[]]
]
```

Comment: You want a list as your output?

Comment: It can be either list or another dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the 1st `df1` to dict

```
df2.apply(lambda x : x.map(df1.set_index(1).T.to_dict('l'))).values.tolist()
Out[147]: [[[5, 7], [9, 11], [15, 17]], [[7, 9], [11, 13], nan]]
```

If you want a data frame

```
d=df2.apply(lambda x : x.map(df1.set_index(1).T.to_dict('l')))
d
Out[164]: 
        1         2         3
0  [5, 7]   [9, 11]  [15, 17]
1  [7, 9]  [11, 13]       NaN
```

One more step replace `NaN` to `[]`:

```
d.loc[d[3].isnull(),3] = d.loc[d[3].isnull(),3].apply(lambda x: [])
d
Out[184]: 
        1         2         3
0  [5, 7]   [9, 11]  [15, 17]
1  [7, 9]  [11, 13]        []
```